# Invertible Functions are Exponentials of compactly supported functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, exponential-function

Let $C'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself.  If $g \in C'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ has the property that $g(x)=x$ outside the closed unit ball and $g$ fixed the origin , then can we necessarily represent $g$ as
$$
g = exp(
Af(|x|) +b
) x,
$$
where $A$ is a $d\times d$ invertible matrix $b\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ is acontinuous and compactly supported function, and $\exp$ is the matrix exponential.

Comment: No, because this formula would imply that $g$ can only be $0$ at $x=0$. There are many functions that are $0$ on other points as well.

Comment: Thank you, I was invishioning affine transformations (invertible) of this map.  I added the constraint.

Comment: No, consider $d=1$. $g$ could be negative for $x \in (0, 1)$ but $\exp(h(x))x > 0$ for all $h$.